# A non-convex set with $\partial x = 0$ but does depend on $ x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

Question states:
"Let $f: S \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable and let $s \subset \Bbb R^n$. Furthermore, let $\partial _1 f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in S$. Show that if $S$ is convex, then $f$ doesn't depend on $x_1$ (meaning $f(a) = f(b)$ if $a$ and $b$ only differ in the first component). Is this still true if $S$ is not convex?"

I just wanted to make sure that my proof for the second part is correct.

Consider the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x+y}$ and the set $S=\{(0,0), (2,-1), (16,-2)\}$. $\partial _x f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y+2xy^4}{(x+y^3)^2}$, and it can be verified that $\partial _1 f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in S$. However, $f$ is dependent on $x$.

If my proof isn't correct, why is that, and what is the correct approach to the problem?

Comment: A function has to be defined on an open set to be differentiable, so really $S$ should be open. A simpler example is to take $S$ to be the union of two disjoint open balls. Then set $f=1$ on one ball and $f=2$ on the other. All partials of $f$ are zero in $S$, but f depends on $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure, an interval in $\Bbb R$ works too, right?

Comment: But come to think of it, that would make $f$ not continuous and therefore not differentiable.

Comment: The balls are disjoint, so $f$ is smooth. In $\mathbb{R}$ take, for instance, $S = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$, and set $f(x)=1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=2$ for $x \in (2,3)$. Then $f$ is a smooth function on $S$, and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in S$, but $f$ depends on $x$.